# Same affiliation for all authors without extra packages

Tags: titles, affiliation

I have a working paper with a colleague from the same institution, so we entered:

```
\author{A B \and C d}
```

how can I now add affiliation, so that its for both authors (centred), and not only for one of them? I would prefer not to use extra packages if possible.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The simplest solution (which is not to say it is the best) is not to use `\and`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Foo}
\author{Author One\qquad Author Two\\Affiliation}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's really most simple. (+1)

Comment: Should read "simplest" not "most simple".

Comment: @mefathy, both are correct.

Comment: @TH. It is surprising to me that "most simple" is also correct. But it is far less commonly used though. 
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/429/most-simple-or-simplest

Comment: simplemost  ; - )

Answer (score 12):

At the moment I see no other solution than using e. g. the [authblk](http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk) package. For details please refer to the package manual.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{Two Authors with same Affiliation}
\author{Author One}
\author{Author Two}
\affil{Affiliation}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The [blindtext](http://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext) package is only for creating dummy text thus not part of the solution

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Donig for very helpful answer. I do a have a similar question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303678/4821). Would highly appreciate if you have a look on this and provide any answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For cleaner definition, another solution is to use the `\publishers{}` field of Koma-Script classes.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\title{Foo}
\author{Author One \and Author Two}
\publishers{Affiliation}
\date{\today}                          %or \date{} to not print date
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

N.B.: use `\and` between each authors.

Comment: If `\date{}` is not empty, this prints the affiliation after the date, which can look weird (author and affiliation are separated).

Answer (score 2):

Here's my usual trick.  (My coauthor taught me this; I've met at least one person who really hates it based on semantic markup reasons, but I like it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Foo}
\author{Author One\and Author Two}
\date{Affiliation}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: This method does "work", i.e., it will indeed produce output that's somewhat reasonable-looking in many "normal" circumstances. What's problematic about it -- apart from the rather non-semantic approach -- is (a) spacing between the `author` and `date` blocks can only be modified by resorting to further hacking, (b) hackish code will be needed if you need to display a real date below the affiliation line, and (c) the (possibly remote) possibility of a page break occuring between the author and date blocks.

Comment: I accept accusations (a) and (b).  But (c) is just silly.  The `\textheight` would have to be under two inches for that to happen!  If your page is that small, chances are just about everything will break anyway.  Even beamer has bigger "pages" than that.

Comment: I regret you feel my discussion points amount to accusations. I will reject the label "silly" for the third point. Quite often, a title page features an image or logo, and the height of this logo can easily be half the height of the text block -- or more. I take it that your papers never feature such image files on the title page, and that's fine. However, it doesn't mean it never happens in other papers. At the very least, it's worth pointing out the risk of an unwanted page break occurring if the authors' names and their (common) affiliation are not part of the same block.

Comment: I was using the term accusation as tongue in cheek :)  You're right, I never used a logo or anything, and it didn't even occur to me as a possibility.