# Custom positions of author names, affiliations and emails in LaTeX article

Tags: article, affiliation, authblk, email

I'm looking for custom positions of  author names, affiliations and emails in LaTeX article. I want to have email immediately below the affiliations rather than in the footnote like this.

```
                       My title

   Author A 1,∗ , Author B 1,† , Author C 1,‡ , Author D 2,§ , and Author E 2,¶

         1 Department of Computer Science, L A TEX University
         2 Department of Mechanical Engineering, L A TEX University
         ∗ Corresponding Author: A.A@university.edu
         † B.B@university.edu
         ‡ C.C@university.edu
         § D.D@university.edu
         ¶ E.E@university.edu
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\date{}

\title{My title}

\author[1]{Author A\thanks{Corresponding Author: A.A@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author B\thanks{B.B@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author C\thanks{C.C@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author D\thanks{D.D@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author E\thanks{E.E@university.edu}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}

\section{Intro}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: check the answer mentioned below...@MYaseen208

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the below mentioned code. The screen shot of the output is attached below. You need to remove the `\thanks` part from the author affiliation area. This is because `\thanks` places the e-mail id in the footnote.

Hope this helps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\date{}

\title{My title}

\author[1]{Author A}
\author[1]{Author B}
\author[1]{Author C}
\author[2]{Author D}
\author[2]{Author E}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[ ]{\textit {\{email1,email2,email3,email4,email5\}@xyz.edu}}
%\eid{123@gmail.com}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[2]
\end{abstract}

\section{Intro}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```